# How can I select which button from a toolstrip is checked when the program is initialized using Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form that used to have 4 buttons(btn1,btn2,btn3,btn4) in a toolstrip, I added a new button (btnNew).
When my application starts I wanted this new button to be pre selected.

I tried changing in the properties of btnNew to "checked = true" and "checkstate = checked".
But when I start the application my new button is not selected!

What is weird is that all of the other buttons are "checked=false" and "Checkstate=unchecked".
If I selected one of the old buttons before closing the program, when I start it again the last selected button is still selected.
Except for the btnNew, independent of the which btn is with the "checked=true" state it is the only that is never pre selected when it re-starts.

And if change the "checked" and "checkstate" for the other buttons they also are not initialized selected.
With the exception for the btn4! This one is always selected when started but if I select another button before closing, then they both are selected when started (and I really don't want these!!!)

I would accept if the last select is still selected when it restarts or any button select tbh.
Do you guys have any idea of what could be causing it or how to solve it?
Seriously, any ideas are welcome!

Comment: The behavior you're describing (the button being focused CHANGING upon startup) is not possible unless you put code in your application to change the TabIndex order, or by explicitly setting focus to something in the Load()/Shown() event.  Did you do either of these things?

Comment: I have nor changed it and there was no focus nor TabIndexes, I have changed it now and it did the job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possibilities. First you can call the method Focus  of the related button. Another way is to adjust the TabIndex of all of your controls.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.focus?view=netcore-3.1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tabindex?view=netcore-3.1#System_Windows_Forms_Control_TabIndex

Answer (score 0):

I will assume when you say button you are talking about a `ToolStripButton`, and when you say selected you mean pressed. The property `CheckOnClick` must be set to True for the button to remain pressed.